# Change bar color in bar chart based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I am trying to set the bar color based on value with follow condition.
it is setting **#EE543D** for all bars.

```
function createObject(vals) {
    var rtnData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length / 2; i++) {
        rtnData.push({
            "country": vals[i * 2 + 0],
            "visits": vals[i * 2 + 1],
            "lineColorcountry": (vals[i * 2 + 1] > 99.8) ? "#69BB1D" : (vals[i * 2 + 1] > 99.6) ? "#FFFF00" : "#EE543D"

        });
    }
    return rtnData;
}
```

Comment: If you want a serious answer, please consider posting your actual data as well. BTW, this has nothing to do with the charts. It's a JavaScript question.

Answer (score -1):

Look what value return your 'vals[0]'. If i give parameter '99.7', that array element return 9. Something it's wrong. You use in Your function parameters like array elements, but in my opinion they are not that.

I would try use rest parametres from ES 2015 spec.

Change your 
    `function createObject(vals)`

to
    `function createObject(...vals)`

that will make array from your parameters :)

Comment: vals[i*2+1] is returning correct value i,e 100 which i can see on graph as well